# My uploaded files are stored on the server without format How to add a format to a file and submit that file to a web service in php?

Tags: php

I need to use the file this way :

```
        'file'=> new CURLFILE("1.jpg"));
```

My files are saved here like this:[image: file without extention]

The format of these files is JPG

What should I write instead of ***1.Jepg?***

Comment: the `e9c55359-96ae-3b42-2605-6288ae4f4342` is the filename instead `1.Jpeg`

Comment: yes but i cannot use that
my files has not format
 i write .jpg after file name it is incorrect because there is no file with that name.
and if i write only name without format it is incorrect because i have to send file only with jpg format to webservice

Comment: well your files do not have extensions, you can rename them to have it or provide your own like: `'file'=> new CURLFile('e9c55359-96ae-3b42-2605-6288ae4f4342', 'image/jpeg', '1.jpg')` see docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'file'=> new CURLFile('e9c55359-96ae-3b42-2605-6288ae4f4342', 'image/jpeg', '1.jpg'
```

Answer (score 0):

What is `CURLFILE` ? Is it a typo of `CURLFile` or is it a custom made class ?

You may try something like this:
`'image' => new CURLFile('Your_File', 'image/jpeg', 'image')`.

Comment: yes CURLFILE  is a typo of CURLFile

Comment: i can not write PATH\1.jpg
because my file in server has not any format (jpg)
if i write .jpg after file name 
it is incorrect because  there is no file with that name

Comment: Using 'your_file' instead of PATH\1.jpg (see my edit) is not working either ?